# removeObserver, addObserver, NSPredicate, PFQuery what are they?

Tags: swift, nspredicate, pfquery

ok i have a few questions about functions that are called in a swift app that i just downloaded

1) what is addObserver and removeObserver. what is an observer.

```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "displayPushMessage:", name: "displayMessage", object: nil)**
```

//    }

```
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "displayMessage", object: nil)
```

2)   what is NSPredicate???

```
           let pred = NSPredicate(format: "user1 = %@ OR user2 = %@", PFUser.currentUser(), PFUser.currentUser())



    3) //what is PFQuery???





    let roomQuery = PFQuery(className: "Room", predicate: pred)

    roomQuery.orderByDescending("lastUpdate")

    roomQuery.includeKey("user1")

    roomQuery.includeKey("user2")
```

Comment: How about a look into Apple's documentation. Try CMD-ciick and Alt-click on the NS-classes.

Comment: `PFQuery` is related to a "cloud" database from parse.com.  There's information on that site.  The others are in the docs that come with Xcode, as stated above.

Comment: You should read the documentation from apple. If any doubts then ask specifically

Answer (score 0):

Add and remove Observer is actually design pattern that you get "by default" in swift. They listen to the certain event and then notify listeners (observers) about that change. For instance, take a look at your example:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "displayPushMessage:", name: "displayMessage", object: nil)
```

This will create observer in notification center. Actual observer is the object that is setting this particular observer ( e.g. View controller ). That observer will have to have displayPushMessage implemented with argument of `NSNotification`. After this observer is notified that something happened, this method will be called. NSNotification contains `object` that you can cast to your own object, and that object you will send with particular data. You can also set the name for the observer.

Here is an example of sending data with notification with some object. Let ObserverExample be your custom class, and you want that object to send to notification. Then you will have method called sendNotification or post or whatever. In that method use this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("Hello", object: self)
```

Your method accepting this will look something like

```
func displayPushMessage:(notification:NSNotification){
    var myObject = notification.object as! ObserverExample!
}
```

Then, you can extract data that you want from myObject which is ObserverExample class.

Remove observer method is used to remove observer from Notification center after you done some logic, or you don't want to listen to it, or whatever your reason to remove it is.

`NSPredicate` is used to filter, order or get particular data from dataset. Can be used with array, dictionary, CoreData etc. you can find a lot of examples about this one, here is the one that will get you object with particular id:

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", someId)
```

and later, you can use it as follows (with Realm for instance):

```
let results = realm.objects(MyObject).filter(predicate)
```

Regarding PFQuery, this is parse class, and the Parse is actually database as a service provider for online database. Alternative is Firebase, for example. You can find more here: https://parse.com/